# Decode x265 nal_unit to yuv with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, yuv, hevc

I'm writing a kind of skype application in which I first encode the video with x265 encoder. Below you can see the settings of the encoder and the line to encode the video and get the nal_units.

```
x265_param_default_preset(param, "ultrafast", "zerolatency");
x265_param_parse(param, "fps", "30");
x265_param_parse(param, "input-res", "160x120"); //wxh
x265_param_parse(param, "bframes", "3");
x265_param_parse(param, "rc-lookahead", "5");
x265_param_parse(param, "repeat-headers", "1");

x265_nal *pp_nal=NULL;
uint32_t pi_nal=0;

int encoded = x265_encoder_encode(encoder, &pp_nal, &pi_nal, pic_in, pic_recon);
```

After this I send the pp_nal and pi_nal to the client and then I would like to decode these nal_units to yuv with ffmpeg. I initialize my decoder:

```
AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecContext *av_codec_context = NULL;
avcodec_register_all();

int frame_count;
FILE *f;
AVFrame *frame;
AVPacket avpkt;
av_init_packet(&avpkt);

codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H265);
if (!codec) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
    exit(1);
}

av_codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!av_codec_context) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
    exit(1);
}
av_codec_context->width = 160;
av_codec_context->height = 120;
av_codec_context->extradata = NULL;
av_codec_context->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

/* open it */
if (avcodec_open2(av_codec_context, codec, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
    exit(1);
}
AVFrame *av_frame_ = av_frame_alloc();
frame_count = 0;
int got_frame;
```

And then for every nal packet I execute the following:

```
AVPacket av_packet;
av_new_packet(&av_packet, pp_nal->sizeBytes);
av_packet.data = (uint8_t *) pp_nal->payload;
av_packet.size = pp_nal->sizeBytes;

avcodec_decode_video2(av_codec_context, av_frame_, &got_frame, &av_packet);
```

But this doesn't work and gives the followig error 'Error parsing nal unit'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I suspect you either need to set the extradata fields in the codec context, or switch x265 to use annexB. But I am making  assumptions that the h264 bitstream is similar to the h254.

Comment: seconding @szatmary comment, with the same assumption